# Whitehead theorem for cohomotopy

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Recall that the cohomotopy set $\pi^k(\mathcal{M})$ is $[\mathcal{M},S^k]$, i.e., the set of pointed homotopy classes of continuous mappings $\mathcal{M}\to S^k$. Recall also the Whitehead theorem:

> **Theorem:** *Suppose $X,Y$ are connected CW complexes. Suppose then that $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map which induces an isomorphism $f_{*}:\pi_k(X,x_0)\to\pi_K(Y,f(x_0))$ for any $x_0\in X$. Then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.*

**Does the following conjecture hold?**

> **Conjecture:** *Suppose $X,Y$ are connected CW complexes. Suppose then that $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map which induces an isomorphism $f^{*}:\pi^k(Y)\to\pi^k(X)$. Then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.*

An obvious motivation comes from the Whitehead theorem. The only lead I have on finding a proof of this conjecture is a theorem of Hopf states that $\pi^k(X)$ is in bijection with $H^k(M)$.

Comment: Should it be $f^*: \pi^k(Y) \rightarrow \pi^k(X)$?

Comment: I mean $\pi^k$ should be contravariant instead of covariant in the statement you want to prove?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this is false.  According to the Sullivan Conjecture (Miller's Theorem), 
$\mathrm{map}_*(B\mathbb{Z}/p, S^n) \sim *$ for all $n$, which means
$$
[\Sigma^n B\mathbb{Z}/p, S^k] = *
$$
for all $n$.  So if we let $f: \Sigma^k \mathbb{Z}/ p \to *$, the induced map
$$
f^*: 
\pi^k(*) 
\to 
\pi^k ( \Sigma^n B\mathbb{Z}/p ) 
$$
is the equivalence $* \to *$.  Since $f$ is not a homotopy equivalence, this counterexamps the conjecture.

Perhaps it would be more interesting to restrict attention to
maps $f:X\to Y$ between finite complexes.

EDIT (further thoughts):  If $K$ and $L$ are finite complexes, then something like your co-Whitehead statement is true!

Theorem 1:  If $f: K\to L$ is a map of finite complexes such that $\pi^k( \Sigma^n f)$ is an isomorphism for all $k\geq k_0$ and all $n \geq n_0$, then $\Sigma f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Corollary 2:  In Theorem 1, if both $K$ and $L$ are simply-connected, then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

The proof uses a theorem of mine:

Theorem M:  If $X$ is simply-connected and of finite type and $\mathrm{map}_*(X,S^k) \sim *$ for all sufficiently large $k$, then $\mathrm{map}(X,Y)\sim *$ for all finite-dimensional CW complexes $Y$.

Proof of Theorem 1:  The hypotheses imply that the cofiber $C_{\Sigma^{n_0} f} \simeq \Sigma^{n_0} C_f$
satisfies $\mathrm{map}_*(\Sigma^{n_0} C_f, S^k) \sim *$ for all $k \geq k_0$.  Theorem M implies that $\mathrm{map}_*(\Sigma^{n_0} C_f, \Sigma^{n_0}C_f) \sim *$, which implies $\Sigma^{n_0} C_f \sim *$ and hence that $\Sigma C_f \sim *$.  This suffices to show that $\Sigma f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: What do you mean by "of finite type"?

Comment: Homotopy equivalent to a CW complex with finitely many cells in each dimension.

Comment: In this case there's something wrong with the statement of theorem M. Let $X = S^2$, then for all $k \gg 1$, $\pi^k(S^2) = 0$ while the corollary is false.

Comment: *Counterexamps* is a word? (Third person singular, apparently.)

Comment: No, the theorem has a condition on the space of maps, not just the set of homotopy classes.

Answer (score 18):

No, certainly not. If $X$ is a space with trivial reduced integral homology (for example the Poincare homology sphere with a ball removed) then the cohomotopy sets are all trivial, like those of a point.

EDIT  Here are some details. Suppose $X$ has trivial homology, therefore trivial cohomology for all constant coefficients. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a based map with $Y$ connected and $\pi_1Y$ abelian. $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to a space that fibers over a $K(G,1)$ with $1$-connected fiber $Y_2$. $f$ can be lifted to a map $f_2:X\to Y_2$. $Y_2$ is homotopy equivalent to a space that fibers over a $K(G,2)$ with $2$-connected fiber $Y_3$. $f_2$ can be lifted to a map $X\to Y_{3}$, and this process can be repeated indefinitely. In the limit $f$ is lifted to an $\infty$-connected space, showing that it is homotopic to a constant.

Comment: Would you mind to give more hint on the answer? I thought it is because when we look at the AHSS and set $E = S^0$ since we have no homology the spectral sequence is trivial but I think this might only be the stable case: when we use $S^0$ as a cohomology theory we already suspend it enough times. So I think I must miss the reason why trivial reduced homology implies trivial cohomotopy and the reason should be very simple.

Comment: I was thinking of using the Postnikov tower of the sphere.

Comment: I've puzzled over this for some time now.  I know it is true if $X$ is $2$-dimensional, for then $\pi^k = 0$ for $k > 2$, $\pi^1 (X)= \widetilde H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ because $S^1 = K(\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ and $\pi^2 =  \widetilde H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$ by Hopf.  But if $\mathbf{dim}(X) > 2$, how do you approach the middle cohomology?

Comment: I have added some details.

Comment: Good, so the theorem is:  if $\Sigma X \simeq *$, then $[X,Y] = *$ for any space with a Postnikov tower.  I didn't know that before.

Comment: What's a space without a Postnikov tower?

Comment: Well, non-nilpotent spaces, right?

Comment: @Jeff Strom, I guess you mean a Postnikov tower of principal fibrations. By the way, if you want a more general result, I think the following holds: if $X$ is acyclic and $Y$ has hypoabelian fundamental group (i.e. the fundamental group has no non-trivial perfect subgroup), then any map $f:X\to Y$ is null. I think you can prove it by using a generalized Postnikov tower for $Y$ originally given by Robinson (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256052280). (to be continued...)

Comment: (continuation) Then observe that this generalized Postnikov tower provides obstruction groups for extending $f$ to a map $CX\to Y$ (where $CX$ is the cone on $X$). These obstruction groups are identified with relative cohomology groups of the pair $(CX,X)$ with local coefficients. Finally, since $X$ is acyclic, all these relative cohomology groups are zero (i.e. the map $X\to CX\simeq\ast$ is acyclic). The condition on the fundamental group of $Y$ is there just to deal with the very first lift to $K(\pi_1 Y,1)$, which does not correspond to any cohomology/obstruction group.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade -- This is pretty cool.  I ran across the "hypoabelian" condition in the work leading to "Theorem M" in the edit to my answer above.

Answer (score 10):

Let me just add that stably it is true that a map f: $X\xrightarrow{} Y$ between finite complexes that induces isomorphisms on cohomotopy (of all degrees, now, including negative) is a weak equivalence.  This is because the collection of all Z such that 
$f^{*} : [Y,Z] \xrightarrow{} [X,Z]$
is an isomorphism is a thick subcategory (also closed under products)
so if it contains the spheres it contains all finite complexes.  It is not true for general Y and Z because there are many many spectra with no cohomotopy at all; the Morava K-theories for example.

This also points to what goes wrong unstably, because mapping out of things behaves well with respect to fibrations, not cofibrations.  So you'd expect the co-Whitehead theorem to be true not for finite complexes, but for spaces that can be built from spheres by taking iterated total spaces of fibrations; Lie groups for example, maybe.

Comment: Do you really need to assume the cohomotopy isomorphism for all degrees?  Can you get away with "sufficiently large" values?

Comment: I think you cannot get away with sufficiently large values.  Suppose X and Y are finite complexes, with the top cell in degree n.  Then the cohomotopy in large degrees is going to be 0 for both of them.  So the question is sort of the wrong way around, it seems to me; one should instead ask if you know about low (negative) cohomotopy can you conclude something.